# Automatically Creating Accounts using Dropbox SDK

Tags: php, mysql, dropbox

I have a new social-network like web app coming up, and I want a space where a user can upload a file and see the files he has uploaded.

Of course, I am already a user of dropbox and found out they have numerous sdk's to use. I was hoping I could now integrate dropbox into my web app.

When a user signs up for my application, it should create a new dropbox account for them (without asking), using the email they are also supplied when signing up. It should then let the user access the files on the dropbox website, through the application or using the desktop app.

Is this at all possible?

Web App is in PHP with support of MySQL.

Comment: Imaging the fun if hotmail/yahoo/gmail allowed joerandom to create accounts remotely. All those penis pill-pushing hot russian brides who have fantastic work-from-home opportunities to transship goods to eastern europe jobs would solve the world economic crisis!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not right now, and I really doubt it will ever be possible. Imagine a bot just creating thousands of accounts; or someone just using it as their hosting service... (*cough* ;))

Comment: Thanks, I ended up emailing them to see if they can help me out.